# Alternative to node-set function

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am facing an issue with while compiling XSLT version with Node-Set function.

So I would like to find alternative of Node-Set function.

Input

```
Input XML
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Input_DT xmlns="http://siemens.com/ad/geb/cartmanagement/1.2" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Description>RCBO, 10 kA, 4P, type AC, 30 mA, C-Char, In: 125 A, Un AC: 400 V</Description>
</Input_DT>

XSLT:
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
     xmlns:doc="http://siemens.com/ad/geb/cartmanagement/1.2" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
     exclude-result-prefixes="i doc"
    extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/doc:Input_DT">
        <xsl:variable name="result">
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="doc:Description"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
    
    
    <xsl:for-each select="ext:node-set($result)/*" >
    <pos><xsl:value-of select="position()"/> </pos>
    <printtokValue>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
    </printtokValue>
    </xsl:for-each>
    
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template name="tokenize">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="','"/>
            <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
            <xsl:if test="$token">
                <Number>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$token"/>
                </Number>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
                <!-- recursive call -->
                <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Would it possible here to write code without node-set () since SAP version does not support node-set() function?

Thank you very much

With Best Regards,
Sateesh N

Comment: Please post a [mcve], not extensive snippets of code taken out of context. Include also an example of input and the expected output. Also, why do you need (or think that you need) to eliminate the use of `node-set()`?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes  , I have given example of input XML and XSLT .  and reason is SAP doesn't support node-set () function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really needed, you could eliminate the need for the `node-set()` function by letting the tokenizing template do all the work and write directly to the output:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:doc="http://siemens.com/ad/geb/cartmanagement/1.2" 
exclude-result-prefixes="doc">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/doc:Input_DT">
    <root>
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="doc:Description"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="','"/>
    <xsl:param name="i" select="1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
    <xsl:if test="$token">
        <pos>
            <xsl:value-of select="$i"/> 
        </pos>
        <printtokValue>
            <xsl:value-of select="$token"/> 
        </printtokValue>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However I doubt you really need this. A quick Google search shows that SAP does support the `node-set()` function in its own namespace - see: https://help.sap.com/saphelp_snc700_ehp01/helpdata/en/a8/824c3c66177414e10000000a114084/frameset.htm